# Meaning of this conversion

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, phrase-meaning

Someone has told me like this:

"be free and grow into the future not the past."

what message he want to give me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means to move on, and don't let mistakes and other unfortunate things in life bring you down.

Comment: Agree with frost

Comment: another message is to not to dwell in the past.